# Has anyone managed to extract a list of all Azure Active Directory users through Powershell within Azure Function App?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, export-to-csv

I've a Powershell script (below) that extracts a list of 'AccountEnabled' Azure Active Directory (AAD) users (approx. 35k users and 13MB in file size) which runs fine on my local machine although it takes a while (approx. 10 minutes)

However, when I deploy the code to Azure Function App using Durable Functions (tried both Consumption & Premium EP1 Plan) and do a test run, it authenticates successfully but from the log, it keeps repeating "no traces within the x minutes". When I inspect the blob storage location where the file is meant to be exported to, the file size is initially around 1.4MB but after a few minutes it seems to get replaced with a file of 700kB size and then 0kB size which is weird. Left it running for hours and nothing happened.

I then modified the script to only list users where their UserPrincipalName starts with the letter 'a' and it ran fine on Azure Functions; i.e: exported approx. 3k users in about 2 minutes and the Azure Function log shows it ran successfully too.

I'm kinda new to Azure Function and not sure where's the bottleneck/issue so it will be much appreciated if someone can please shed some light on it. Thanks in advance.

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter 'AccountEnabled eq true' | Select-Object DeletionTimestamp,ObjectId,
ObjectType,AccountEnabled,AgeGroup,City,CompanyName,Country,CreationType,Department,DirSyncEnabled,
DisplayName,FacsimileTelephoneNumber,GivenName,IsCompromised,JobTitle,LastDirSyncTime,LegalAgeGroupClassification,
Mail,MailNickName,Mobile,OtherMails,PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName,PostalCode,PreferredLanguage,
RefreshTokensValidFromDateTime,ShowInAddressList,SignInNames,State,StreetAddress,Surname,TelephoneNumber,
UsageLocation,UserPrincipalName,UserState,UserStateChangedOn,UserType,
@{name='Licensed';expression={if($_.AssignedLicenses){$TRUE}else{$False}}},
@{name='Plan';expression={if($_.AssignedPlans){$TRUE}else{$False}}}, 
@{N="EmployeeId";E={$_.ExtensionProperty["employeeId"]} },
@{N="CreatedDateTime";E={$_.ExtensionProperty["createdDateTime"]} }
| Export-csv $FilePath -NoTypeInformation #stores results in a csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your function times out. Have you tried to configure [functionTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout)?

If your code requires more than 60 minutes on Premium or more than 10 minutes on Consumption, and you can split processing into smaller parts (e.g. by the first letter), consider using [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=powershell): you can use either **Function chaining** or **Fan out/fan in** pattern. The timeout will be applied to each activity invocation individually, but the entire orchestration execution time is unlimited.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Anatoli. Yes, I did configure my host.json file to have a functionTimeout of an hour (thinking that should be enough). Will increase that and give it a shot again.

And yes, I'm actually using Durable Functions but the test I mentioned earlier was purely through the Test/Run within the Activity function. Just to clarify and sorry if it's a dumb question, when you mentioned Function chaining or Fan out/fan in, do you mean calling the Activity function through the Starter & Orchestrator?

Comment: Yes, activities are normally invoked from an orchestrator function. What I'm proposing is to split the work into smaller pieces that can be completed well within the timeout limit. When activities are invoked from an orchestrator, Durable Functions will automatically persist the partial results, and then the orchestrator will be able to aggregate them. If you just invoke an activity function separately, you can't take advantage of this.

Comment: In terms of splitting the work into smaller pieces, do you mean the following as an example: I will split the single activity into 26 activities (each alphabet of the first letter) and within my single orchestrator, I will list the 26 activities within it so each activity will be invoked by that one orchestrator?

Thanks in advance once again Anatoli. Cheers.

Comment: @Luke88: Yes, this is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Anatoli!

Yesterday I conducted 5 runs of the whole batch (didn't split it into smaller parts yet) by invoking the orchestrator and 3 runs completed successfully while 2 failed. I checked the log activity and following is the error code. Does that imply that the function host restarted and hence, the contention issue on the file that is being exported to?

Comment: ERROR: The process cannot access the file 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\AzureActiveDirectory\AllAccountEnabledUsers\20210204.csv' because it is being used by another process. Exception : Type : System.IO.IOException TargetSite : Name : ValidateFileHandle DeclaringType : System.IO.FileStream MemberType : Method Module : System.Private.CoreLib.dll StackTrace : at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle) at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access...

Comment: @Luke88: Depending on how your scripts look like, it is possible that either multiple activity invocations or multiple orchestrator runs are trying to use this file. Also, this location may not be writeable when you deploy the app to Azure. If you do need a file, I would recommend creating a temp file with a unique name within each activity (use the `New-TemporaryFile` cmdlet).

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip, Anatoli; much appreciated :)